# Help deciphering a young Chinese student's writing!

Tags: translation, handwriting, transcription

[image: Chinese youth hand writing]

Can you tell what this young student wrote during my VIP Kid class? I wrote NiHao in red and he wrote the blue that follows. Keep in mind, there is an awry game of tic tac toe on the right in blue and some large and small smiley faces throughout. I think I made out this much...

Zhe shi wo de (ke zi?) ... ?

I'm looking for the Chinese characters as the student wrote them (probably traditional), pinyin, and a full translation, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

这是我的名字阚鸿博
zhe shi wo de ming zi kan hong bo

This is my name Kan Hongbo

Comment: how did you...??